# How can I add Printer path in C# windows application?

Tags: c#, windows, printing

I followed the a tutorial from the [YouTube](https://youtu.be/0mC_yvT3abw?t=632) to print receipt for my application.
I've added printer path in settings as guided in the video.

[Screenshot of Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfdCx.png)

**The function I used for printing.**

```
private void printReciept()
        {
            try
            {
                Byte[] BytesValue = new Byte[] { };
                BytesValue = GetLogo(@"../../Resources/Bil_Top.png");   // loading logo
               
                BytesValue = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(BytesValue, obj.Alignment.Left());
                BytesValue = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(BytesValue, obj.CharSize.Nomarl());
                // adding Bill details
                BytesValue = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(BytesValue, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("----------------------------------------------------------------\n"));
                BytesValue = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(BytesValue, string.Format("{0,-12}{1,-20}{2,-12}{3,-20:N2}\n", "BillID:", BillIDBox.Text, "Date:", DateBox.Text));
                BytesValue = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(BytesValue, string.Format("{0,-12}{1,-20}{2,-12}{3,-20:N2}\n", "Person ID:", PersonIDBox.Text, "Contact:", ContactTextBox.Text));
                BytesValue = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(BytesValue, string.Format("{0,-12}{1,-30:N2}\n", "Name:", NameTextBox.Text));
                // formating address 
                if((AddressBox.Text).Length<52)
                    BytesValue = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(BytesValue, string.Format("{0,-12}{1,"+(AddressBox.Text).Length+":N2}\n", "Address:", AddressBox.Text));
                else
                {
                    BytesValue = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(BytesValue, string.Format("{0,-12}{1,52:N2}\n", "Address:", AddressBox.Text.Substring(0, 52)));
                    BytesValue = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(BytesValue, string.Format("{0,-12}{1," + ((AddressBox.Text).Length-52) + ":N2}\n", "", AddressBox.Text.Substring(52, ((AddressBox.Text).Length - 52))));
                }
                // adding products info
                BytesValue = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(BytesValue, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("----------------------------------------------------------------\n"));
                BytesValue = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(BytesValue, string.Format("{0,-35}{1,8}{2,6}{3,15:N2}\n", "Name", "Qty", "Dis.", "Price"));
                BytesValue = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(BytesValue, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("----------------------------------------------------------------\n"));
                Decimal T_Qty = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < ProductNum; ++i)
                {
                    T_Qty += Decimal.Parse(ProductArray[i, 4]);
                    BytesValue = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(BytesValue, string.Format("{0,-35}{1,8}{2,6}{3,15:N2}\n", ProductArray[i, 1], ProductArray[i, 4], ProductArray[i, 3], float.Parse(ProductArray[i, 2])));
                }
                BytesValue = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(BytesValue, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("----------------------------------------------------------------\n"));
               
                BytesValue = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(BytesValue, string.Format("{0,-35}{1,8}{2,6}{3,15:N2}\n", "Total", Decimal.Round(T_Qty, 2), TotalDiscountBox.Text, TotalBillBox.Text));
                BytesValue = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(BytesValue, string.Format("{0,-49}{1,15:N2}\n", "Payable Bill", float.Parse(PayableBox.Text)));
                BytesValue = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(BytesValue, string.Format("{0,-49}{1,15:N2}\n", "Amount Paid", PaidBox.Text));
                BytesValue = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(BytesValue, string.Format("{0,-49}{1,15:N2}\n", "Balance", float.Parse(PayableBox.Text)-float.Parse(PaidBox.Text)));
                BytesValue = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(BytesValue, obj.Separator());
                BytesValue = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(BytesValue, obj.Lf());
                BytesValue = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(BytesValue, obj.Alignment.Center());  // resetting printer settings
                
                BytesValue = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(BytesValue, obj.QrCode.Print(BillIDBox.Text, PrinterUtility.Enums.QrCodeSize.Grande));
                BytesValue = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(BytesValue, "\n----------------- Thankyou For Shoping With US -----------------\n");
                BytesValue = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(BytesValue, obj.Alignment.Left());
                BytesValue = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(BytesValue, CutPage());
                // printing bill
                PrinterUtility.PrintExtensions.Print(BytesValue, POS_Project.Properties.Settings.Default.PrinterPath);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot Print beacuse " + e.Message);
            }


        }
```

When ever I tried to print, I am having this error as shown in
[ScreenShot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzEfD.png)

Can anyone please help me out with this?

Comment: As per the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, which you are encouraged to read before using the site, please don't post images of your code. Code is text. Pasting it as graphics is very impractical as it can't be copied, searched, re-used in answers etc. It makes it difficult for those who might want to help you. Please edit your question to include the code as text and use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to present it nicely, so that it is usable for those who want to help you. Thanks

Comment: I've edited the post, check if it is understandable.
Thanks for guiding me @ADyson

Comment: Thanks it's much better. Your printer path looks a bit strange. Normally a UNC path is `\\server\share`, whereas you have got `\\\\server\\share`. Too many backslashes.

Comment: I tried this but Again getting the error:
"Printer path was not found"
@ADyson

Comment: Is this code running on your machine, or on a server somewhere? Have you checked that this path is definitely accessible?

Comment: Yes @ADyson code is running on my machine. For path of printer, I wrote:
**\\Device-Name\Printer Name**
I don't know if this path is correct. I asked the question so that someone can guide me about the path.

Comment: Well we can't see your network so we've no idea how you've configured your printer. The type of path is potentially correct, but only you can check what the real settings are